# asdf cant install node js

Tags: node.js, asdf

i am starting to learn about backend and i needed to install somethings, i followed all the steps but when i try to install nodejs with asdf this error appears, and i dont know what to do, cant install any node versions

node version 18.16.0
asdf version v0.11.3-0adc6c1
npm version 9.5.1
WINDOWS

added plugin nodejs but

```
Trying to update node-build... ok
Downloading node-v18.16.0.tar.gz...
-> https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.16.0/node-v18.16.0.tar.gz
error: failed to download node-v18.16.0.tar.gz
-> https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.16.0/node-v18.16.0.tar.gz
error: failed to download node-v18.16.0.tar.gz

BUILD FAILED (MINGW64_NT-10.0-19044 3.3.4-341.x86_64 using node-build 4.9.116)
```

i tried

```
$ asdf plugin-add nodejs
$ asdf install nodejs 18.16.0
$ asdf global nodejs 18.16.0
```

and expected to be installed and setted

Answer (score -1):

Did you try following commands?

```
asdf update
asdf plugin update --all
```

Or else you could check, if removing aria2c from the PATH fixes the problem.

Comment: i tried but still returning same error

Comment: This never works.